# Copying Array Contents with vDSP

Tags: ios, accelerate-framework

I'm using the accelerate framework to optimize my DSP code.  There are several times when I want to copy the contents of one array (or portion of an array) to another.

I can't seem to find an appropriate function to do this, so instead I've been doing something kind of silly, which is to multiply the array by 1 (or add 0) and get the copy that way.

```
float one = 1;

float sourceArray = new float[arrayLength];
/////....sourceArray is filled up with data

float destArray = new float[arrayLength];

vDSP_vsmul(sourceArray, 1, &one, destArray, 1, arrayLength);
```

there has to be a better way to do this!?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [memcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html)?

```
#include <string.h>

memcpy(destArray, sourceArray, arrayLength * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: This is great if the source and destination strides are 1, but what about non-unity strides?

Comment: This will copy 'arrayLength' floats.  A >1 stride would need to be computed into arrayLength.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine/issues/2) is an comparison between using `vDSP_vsadd` with zero for strided arrays and a plain for loop. As it seems there is no performance difference if they aren't really big... i use the `vDSP_vsadd` all the time for this.

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to use the BLAS portion of Accelerate, Jeff Biggus has benchmarked [`cblas_scopy()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000414-SW25) as being faster than even `memcpy()`.

Comment: This is definitely the exception and not the norm; my advice in general would be to use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

I could think of a lot worse ways that `vDSP_vsmul()`; you could also do `vvcopysign()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `vDSP_vclr` and `vDSP_vadd` as follow:

```
int sourceLength = 3;
float* source = (float*)malloc(sourceLength * sizeof(float));
// source is filled with data, let's say [5, 5, 5]

int destinationLength = 10;
float* destination = (float*)malloc(destinationLength * sizeof(float));
// destination is filled with ones so [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

// Prepare the destination array to receive the source array
// by setting its values to 0 in the range [initialIndex, initialIndex + N-1]
int initialIndex = 2;
vDSP_vclr((destination+initialIndex), 1, sourceLength);

// We add source[0, N-1] into destination[initialIndex, initialIndex + N-1]
vDSP_vadd(source, 1, (destination+initialIndex), 1, (destination+initialIndex), 1, sourceLength);
```

Or more concise you could also use 'cblas_scopy' as Brad Larson said

```
// Init source and destination
// We copy source[0, sourceLength] into destination[initialIndex, initialIndex + sourceLength]
cblas_scopy(sourceLength, source, 1, (destination+initialIndex), 1);
```

Comment: vDSP_vfill fills an array with a scalar value, not values from an array.

Comment: My bad @olynoise . I edited my previous post in order to answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to copy.

Copies the contents of a submatrix to another submatrix; single precision. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449950-vdsp_mmov

```
func vDSP_mmov(_ __A: UnsafePointer<Float>, 
             _ __C: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, 
             _ __M: vDSP_Length, 
             _ __N: vDSP_Length, 
             _ __TA: vDSP_Length, 
             _ __TC: vDSP_Length)
```